# Timeout on advisory locks in postgresql

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, locking, database-migration

I'm migrating from ORACLE. Currently I'm trying to port this call:

```
lkstat := DBMS_LOCK.REQUEST(lkhndl, DBMS_LOCK.X_MODE, lktimeout, true);
```

[This function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lock.htm#i1002556) tries to acquire lock `lkhndl` and returns 1 if it fails to get it after `timeout` seconds.

In postgresql I use

```
pg_advisory_xact_lock(lkhndl);
```

However, it seems that it waits for lock forever. [`pg_try_advisory_xact_lock`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADVISORY-LOCKS) returns immediately if fails. Is there a way to implement timeout version of lock acquiring?

There is [`lock_timeout`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-LOCK-TIMEOUT) setting, but I'm not sure is it applicable to [advisory locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS) and how `pg_advisory_xact_lock` would behave after timeout.

Comment: You can set a `statement_timeout`, say with `SET LOCAL`. Unfortunately it's session (or, with `LOCAL`, transaction) level, not statement level.

Comment: I'm okay with that. But what would happen after timeout? How do I know if the lock was acquired?

Comment: After timeout-ing, the execution is aborted, I don't think you can even catch those errors. To completely simulate that Oracle function, I'm afraid you need to write a re-try loop, with possibly `pg_sleep()` calls (however I'm not sure how that could perform, I never wrote anything like that).

Comment: Oh, I was afraid it would be something like that :(

Comment: Honestly, it seems like we could really use a patch to implement functionality similar to the function you're using in Oracle right now. How's your C programming?

Comment: Enough for programming, not enough for good programming, I think. A patch would be nice, but I afraid it would be worthless for me, as it would be really hard to convince our arch to use unstable version.

Comment: There is no problem/question for Oracle. Oracle tag is useless

Answer (score 1):

This is a prototype of a wrapper that poorly emulates `DBMS_LOCK.REQUEST` - constrained to only one type of lock (transaction-scope advisory lock).

To make function fully compatible with Oracle's, it would need several hundreds lines. But that's a start.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
advisory_xact_lock_request(p_key bigint, p_timeout numeric)
RETURNS integer
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
/*  Imitate DBMS_LOCK.REQUEST for PostgreSQL advisory lock. 
Return 0 on Success, 1 on Timeout, 3 on Parameter Error. */
DECLARE
    t0 timestamptz := clock_timestamp();
BEGIN
    IF p_timeout NOT BETWEEN 0 AND 86400 THEN
        RAISE WARNING 'Invalid timeout parameter';
        RETURN 3;
    END IF;
    LOOP
        IF pg_try_advisory_xact_lock(key) THEN
            RETURN 0;
        ELSIF clock_timestamp() > t0 + (p_timeout||' seconds')::interval THEN
            RAISE WARNING 'Could not acquire lock in % seconds', p_timeout;
            RETURN 1;
        ELSE
            PERFORM pg_sleep(0.01); /* 10 ms */
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

Test it using this code:

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN advisory_xact_lock_request(1, 2.5) = 0
    THEN pg_sleep(120)
END; -- and repeat this in parallel session 

/* Usage in Pl/PgSQL */

lkstat := advisory_xact_lock_request(lkhndl, lktimeout);
```

Comment: Better anwser: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41230942/how-to-avoid-dead-lock-while-using-advisory-locks-in-postgresql/41240274#41240274