# How to avoid dead lock while using advisory locks in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'm using the `pg_advisory_lock` function in postgres which blocks/waits if it's not able to get a lock on a particular key. I was wondering if there is some way to get a timeout on this? I couldn't find anything with what I've looked. If not, is there a way for a session to force release a lock obtained by a different session?

Thanks!

Comment: No built-in timeout feature for getting an advisory lock in Postgres. See [Timeout on advisory locks in postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38853470/642706).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't want to block at all, you can just call [`pg_try_advisory_lock()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADVISORY-LOCKS).

If a blocking `pg_advisory_lock()` call does result in a deadlock, it will automatically time out after the interval specified by the [`deadlock_timeout`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-locks.html#GUC-DEADLOCK-TIMEOUT) setting (one second by default). You can also limit the lock wait time - deadlocked or not - by setting [`lock_timeout`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-LOCK-TIMEOUT) (which by default is disabled).

Note that triggering either of these timeouts will raise an error, so it may be useful to wrap the error handling in a function, e.g.:

```
CREATE FUNCTION pg_try_advisory_lock_with_timeout(key bigint) RETURNS boolean
SET lock_timeout TO '1s'
AS $$
BEGIN
  PERFORM pg_advisory_lock(key);
  RETURN true;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN lock_not_available OR deadlock_detected THEN
    RETURN false;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: This answer helped me! Thanks https://github.com/mpyw/laravel-database-advisory-lock/pull/7

Answer (score 0):

You can try **idle_in_transaction_session_timeout**

> Terminate any session with an open transaction that has been idle fora
>   longer than the specified duration in milliseconds. This **allows any
>   locks held by that session to be released** and the connection slot to
>   be reused; it also allows tuples visible only to this transaction to
>   be vacuumed. See Section 24.1 for more details about this.

Assume you run Task A --> set lock resource X and set idle_in_transaction_session_timeout=1s --> if task A idle > 1s, then task A is automatically terminated and lock X is automatically released. Then task B can get the lock X.

By this way, you can avoid deadlock of resource X.